# Angular tab condition test

Tags: angular, tabs

I have a tab:

```html
 <li><a href="#tab_2-2" target="_self" data-toggle="tab">Test</a></li>
```

I need that tab to be disabled if a checkbox named test on first tab is not checked.

I need to do it in angular.

Answer (score 0):

Html anchor does not have a disable property.

You could use hidden

```
<li><a href="#tab_2-2" target="_self" data-toggle="tab" [hidden]="!test">Test</a></li>
```

Or you could use a condition to remove the href and add disabled class to change the css styling

```
<li><a [href]="test? # : #tab_2-2" [class.disabled]="!test" target="_self" data-toggle="tab">Test</a></li>
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: can you clarefy how you add it to a checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable for tab and set **`[disabled]`** based on it.

**`enableTab = false;`**

```
<tab [disabled] = "enableTab">
```

make it to true when you check your checkbox on tab1,

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="test" (change)="enableTab()" />
```

in TS

```
enableTab(){
  this.enableTab= true;
}
```

Comment: @user613507 what do you mean

Comment: i dont have any element <tab>

Comment: that is just an example

Comment: can you please make this again
where did you put enable tab?